# Adding an iphone icon to a DotNetNuke site

Tags: iphone, icons, dotnetnuke

First and foremost I apologize if this question is not programmer per-se but I've been trying to get some details as to why I'm having this particular problem.

When you view this page on your phone http://www.wilsontireandservice.com/mobile.aspx I would like it when you bookmark a site to your menu it shows up as an icon. On droid phones this was fairly easy to do by just adding this link in the markup:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/Portals/71/Icon.png" />
```

Which is placed inside the skin.ascx file.

However, when trying to do this on an iPhone, I can't seem to get the thing to work. the Icon file is 57x57. I've tried changing the name (`Icon.png`, `apple_touch_icon.png`, `apple-touch-icon.png`), I tried moving the image changing the path to the root folder instead. I placed it inside an HTML module set to repeat on all pages in the header (under settings) with no luck.

We are currently running DNN 5 if it matters, what I'm wondering is there some kind of restriction on doing this within DNN or my version too out of date (we're moving to DNN 6 over the summer), or maybe this has nothing to do with DNN at all.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: That markup didn't carry over but it was: `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/Portals/71/Icon.png" />`

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be DNN specific. Follow [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/set-iphone-bookmark-icon/). You can try it on a blank html page to make sure DNN isn't affecting it.